# JPA:EclipseLink Batch writing not working as expected

Tags: optimization, jpa, eclipselink, batch-processing

I am trying to implement the batch writing to improve the performance of the particular peice of code.
Right now I have written the test case to see what happens when I turn ON the batch-writing in eclipse link.
From the logs it looks like that batch is getting created for each of the insert statements which is not what I expected.
Below is the test case

```
@Test
    public void test_batchCreateRouters(){
        List<RouterDTO> routerDTOList = new ArrayList<RouterDTO>();
        IRouterService iRouterService = (IRouterService) ctx.getBean("routerService");
        build_DTO("Test8",routerDTOList);
        build_DTO("Test2",routerDTOList);
        build_DTO("Test3",routerDTOList);
        build_DTO("Test4",routerDTOList);
        build_DTO("Test5",routerDTOList);
        build_DTO("Test6",routerDTOList);
        build_DTO("Test7",routerDTOList);
        for(RouterDTO routerDTO:routerDTOList) {
            iRouterService.createRouter(routerDTO);
        }
    }
```

build_DTO just populates the DTO and add it the list
createRouter will do some validation and execeute below code:

```
try {
    getJpaTemplate().persist(entity);    
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
throw re;}.
```

But when I check the logs ,i get like below which shows that for each insert ,new batch is created.
Has someone any idea about this or can lead to me the right place.

> [EL Finest]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.218--ServerSession(598639019)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection
>   acquired from connection pool [default].  [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.218--ClientSession(1274943796)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--begin
>   transaction   [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.219--ClientSession(1274943796)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Begin
>   batch statements  [EL Fine]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.22--ClientSession(1274943796)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--INSERT
>   INTO ROUTER_QUANTITY (ROUTER_QUANTITY_ID, ROUTER_PERIOD_ID, COMMENTS,
>   CONTRACT_ID, COUNTER_PARTY, CREATED_BY, CREATED_ON,
>   FACILITY_COMPONENT_ID, LAST_UPDATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_ON, MODIFIED,
>   QUANTITY, QUANTITY_TEMPLATE_ID, SERVICE_ID, SOURCE, STATUS) VALUES (?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [EL Fine]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.221--ClientSession(1274943796)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--    bind
>   => [Test8, 1, Test, 1, Test, user1, 2012-09-18 11:55:56.003, PIMTEST, user1, 2012-09-18 11:55:56.003, Test, 100.1, FM_RES, INJ, Test, Test]
>     [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.221--ClientSession(1274943796)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--End
>   Batch Statements  [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.435--UnitOfWork(233788733)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--end
>   unit of work flush    [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.436--UnitOfWork(233788733)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--resume
>   unit of work  [EL Finest]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.436--UnitOfWork(233788733)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute
>   query ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=AuditTable sql="SELECT
>   AUDIT_TABLE_ID, AUDIT_CREATE, AUDIT_DELETE, AUDIT_READ, AUDIT_UPDATE,
>   CREATED_BY, CREATED_ON, LAST_UPDATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_ON, TABLE_NAME
>   FROM AUDIT_TABLE WHERE (TABLE_NAME = ?)")     [EL Fine]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.44--ClientSession(1274943796)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT
>   AUDIT_TABLE_ID, AUDIT_CREATE, AUDIT_DELETE, AUDIT_READ, AUDIT_UPDATE,
>   CREATED_BY, CREATED_ON, LAST_UPDATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_ON, TABLE_NAME
>   FROM AUDIT_TABLE WHERE (TABLE_NAME = ?)       bind => [ROUTER_QUANTITY]
>     [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.468--UnitOfWork(233788733)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--begin
>   unit of work commit   [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.469--ClientSession(1274943796)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--commit
>   transaction   [EL Finest]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.5--ServerSession(598639019)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection
>   released to connection pool [default].    [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.5--UnitOfWork(233788733)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--end
>   unit of work commit   [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.5--UnitOfWork(233788733)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--resume
>   unit of work  [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.501--UnitOfWork(233788733)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--release
>   unit of work  [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.501--ClientSession(1274943796)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--client released     [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.502--ServerSession(598639019)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--client
>   acquired: 1625102195  [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.502--ClientSession(1625102195)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--acquire unit of work: 1395568819    [EL Finest]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.563--UnitOfWork(1395568819)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--persist() operation called on:
>   fm.am.integration.dao.jpa.allocationquantity.AllocationQuantity@23597cac.
>     [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.563--UnitOfWork(1395568819)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--begin
>   unit of work flush    [EL Finest]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.564--UnitOfWork(1395568819)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute
>   query
>   InsertObjectQuery(fm.am.integration.dao.jpa.allocationquantity.AllocationQuantity@23597cac)
>     [EL Finest]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.564--ServerSession(598639019)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection
>   acquired from connection pool [default].  [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.568--ClientSession(1625102195)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--begin
>   transaction   [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.569--ClientSession(1625102195)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Begin
>   batch statements  [EL Fine]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.569--ClientSession(1625102195)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--INSERT
>   INTO ROUTER_QUANTITY (ROUTER_QUANTITY_ID, ROUTER_PERIOD_ID, COMMENTS,
>   CONTRACT_ID, COUNTER_PARTY, CREATED_BY, CREATED_ON,
>   FACILITY_COMPONENT_ID, LAST_UPDATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_ON, MODIFIED,
>   QUANTITY, QUANTITY_TEMPLATE_ID, SERVICE_ID, SOURCE, STATUS) VALUES (?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [EL Fine]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.57--ClientSession(1625102195)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])-- bind
>   => [Test2, 1, Test, 1, Test, user1, 2012-09-18 11:55:56.563, PIMTEST, user1, 2012-09-18 11:55:56.563, Test, 100.1, FM_RES, INJ, Test, Test]
>     [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.57--ClientSession(1625102195)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--End
>   Batch Statements  [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.571--UnitOfWork(1395568819)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--end
>   unit of work flush    [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.572--UnitOfWork(1395568819)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--resume
>   unit of work  [EL Finest]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.572--UnitOfWork(1395568819)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute
>   query ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=AuditTable sql="SELECT
>   AUDIT_TABLE_ID, AUDIT_CREATE, AUDIT_DELETE, AUDIT_READ, AUDIT_UPDATE,
>   CREATED_BY, CREATED_ON, LAST_UPDATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_ON, TABLE_NAME
>   FROM AUDIT_TABLE WHERE (TABLE_NAME = ?)")     [EL Fine]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.572--ClientSession(1625102195)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT
>   AUDIT_TABLE_ID, AUDIT_CREATE, AUDIT_DELETE, AUDIT_READ, AUDIT_UPDATE,
>   CREATED_BY, CREATED_ON, LAST_UPDATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_ON, TABLE_NAME
>   FROM AUDIT_TABLE WHERE (TABLE_NAME = ?)       bind => [ROUTER_QUANTITY]
>     [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.575--UnitOfWork(1395568819)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--begin
>   unit of work commit   [EL Finer]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.576--ClientSession(1625102195)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--commit
>   transaction [EL Finest]: 2012-09-18
>   11:55:56.611--ServerSession(598639019)--Connection(1572163248)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection
>   released to connection pool [default].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the log each looks like your are using a new transaction to persist each object, so each object is inserted in a separate transaction, and separate batch.

You need to first begin a transaction and persist all of the objects in the transaction.

You are also causing a flush by executing the query Audit, so avoid this ensure you don't query in between the inserts, or set your flushMode on your EntityManager to COMMIT.

Comment: I was blind not to see the transaction pointcut which I had placed wrongly.Also removing the Audit thing proved useful to enable the batch processing.Thanks